# Azure let's encrypt Application with identifier was not found in the directory

Tags: azure, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to get Let's Encrypt to work with an Azure application, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS70001: 
Application with identifier '8c7f7b34-5dd4-4e6d-a2d1-6204230a353c' was not found in the directory $directory.onmicrosoft.com 
Trace ID: 5ddd33fb-1492-471c-b150-eae50dd71c00 Correlation ID: 58dd627a-19ba-4e1e-936a-20459ff96864 Timestamp: 2018-02-01 15:46:46Z ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpWebRequestWrapper.<GetResponseSyncOrAsync>d__2.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpHelper.<SendPostRequestAndDeserializeJsonResponseAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task`1 task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken(String resource, ClientCredential clientCredential) at LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.ArmHelper.GetToken(IAzureEnvironment model) in J:\Projects\letsencrypt-siteextension\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\ArmHelper.cs:line 41 at LetsEncrypt.Azure.Core.ArmHelper.GetWebSiteManagementClient(IAzureWebAppEnvironment model) in J:\Projects\letsencrypt-siteextension\LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Core\ArmHelper.cs:line 19 at LetsEncrypt.SiteExtension.Controllers.HomeController.Index(AuthenticationModel model) ErrorCode: unauthorized_client StatusCode: 400
```

I followed this guide: https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/20073 but got the error just before the third point.

I don't get what's wrong because I should be using the correct application id:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $app.ApplicationId
Guid
----
8c7f7b34-5dd4-4e6d-a2d1-6204230a353c
```

Comment: Follow this to create your service principal, rest will be easy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: Do you give the application `Contributor` role?